# HttpClient to send JSON String Windows Form app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, json.net, httpclient

I'm writing a DLL but testing with a windows app and I have objects that I convert to JSON via

```
 Private Function SeraializeStoreInfo(objt As JSON_postStoreInfo) As String
     'This takes in an object of the JSON_postStoreInfo class 
     'and converts it to JSON to send
     Dim JsonString As String
     JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objt)
     Return JsonString
 End Function
```

I then want to send this JSON string to a webservice to process. I just want to send the JSON string I've just serialized. When I pass the JasonString in as Content to this function as a string, I get an error saying that

> HttpStringContent is not defined. and that Content must be of the type HttpContent.

How can a get around this?

```
Private Async Function SendStoreInfo(Content As String) As Task(Of String)
     Dim stringContent As New HttpStringContent(Content, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json")
     Dim aClient As New HttpClient()
     'Dim theContent As New StringContent(SR.ReadToEnd(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
     ' Dim theContent As New StringContent(Content, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
     'Post the data 
     Dim aResponse As HttpResponseMessage = Await aClient.PostAsync(theUrl, Content)
     If (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) Then
         'this gets the response 
         StoreResponse = aResponse.ToString
     Else
         'show the response status code 
         Dim failureMsg = "HTTP Status: " + aResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + " – Reason: " + aResponse.ReasonPhrase
     End If
 End Function
```

Comment: Think you are mixing Windows.Web.Http and System.Net.Http objects

Comment: What makes you think that Ryan?